# How can I escape my user generated text with Json.NET in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

I have an aspx page that retrieves some user generated text from the database and passes to JQuery Ajax method as a JSON Object.

The JSON string it self is simple `{"popContent":"<div>html content</div>"}`.
The content may have elements such as single quotes, double quotes, carriage returns etc.
The problem is as I'm using .net framework 2.0, struggling to find a method that would escape these elements.

I have tried to use Json.NET to escape this.  The documentation refers to serializing objects, but not clear on how to escape a string.  Is this possible with Json.NET?  Or should I create an object with this string and serialize that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using JSON.NET.

Since you're using .Net 2.0, you don't have anonymous types and cannot do this:

```
var result = new {
  popContent = "<div>html content</div>"
};
```

So I suggest you create a class that has the appropriate properties, then set the HTML content on the property and use JSON.NET for serialize the entire object.

Something like this:

```
ContentWrapper cw = new ContentWrapper();
cw.PopContent = "<div>html content</div>";
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cw);
```

Comment: I don't think 'JsonConvert' is in JSON.NET 2.0.  I did the following and worked fine. `string json = JavaScriptConvert(myObject);`.  Thanks